# Трансляция динамического элемента со страницы в файл

Tags: python, excel, selenium, requests, beautiful-soup

Как транслировать в txt файл или в Excel быстро изменяющийся элемент на странице? возможно ли это сделать при помощи Selenium или быть может это правильнее реализовать какими-то другими средствами? Если возможно то как? Приведите пожалуйста пример!

Т.е. мне необходимо отслеживать динамический элемент, и как только он обновился, нужно чтобы производилась запись в файле с его новым значением, обновляться элемент может довольно быстро, возможно и сотню раз в секунду, необходимо чтобы не было пропусков, т.е. нужно чтобы именно каждое обновление записывалось в файл. Также необходимо чтобы запись производилась в определенную область в excel файле(например с 1 по 100 строку) , иначе файл будет очень сильно расти, этого не нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать Selenium. Однако, при частом обновлении Selenium будет неэффективным и медленным в использовании. Лучше BeautifulSoup и Requests